# Drop first nan rows in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below `df`:

```
    ID      Number  Number 2  Number 3
1   10001   NaN     NaN       5
2   10001   25      NaN       12
3   10001   78      4         NaN
4   10002   3       NaN       NaN
5   10002   234     201       NaN
6   10002   NaN     510       34
7   10003   NaN     765       NaN
8   10003   NaN     422       NaN
9   10003   NaN     753       56
10  10003   231     7587      2345
```

I want to structure the data so the first NaN rows are deleted by column.

Resuling `df`:

```
    ID      Number Number 2  Number 3
1   10001   25     4         5
2   10001   78     NaN       12
3   10001   NaN    NaN       NaN
4   10002   3      201       34
5   10002   234    510       NaN
6   10002   NaN    NaN       NaN
7   10003   231    765       56
8   10003   NaN    422       2345
9   10003   NaN    753       NaN
10  10003   NaN    7587      NaN
```

I'm essentially trying to shift the column data up by n rows depending on where the data starts for that column, so at the first rows of `ID` there is always data in at least 1 of the `Number` columns.

I've tried `first_row_index` but this doesn't work by individual column

I've tried `dropna` but I can't find a solution where I'm defining what number of rows to drop per column.

Comment: You forgot to say **PER GROUP**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = df.melt('ID').dropna()
df1['var1'] = df1.groupby(['variable', 'ID']).cumcount()
df1.pivot(['ID', 'var1'], 'variable', 'value').reset_index(0)
```

---

```
variable     ID  Number  Number 2  Number 3
var1                                       
0         10001    25.0       4.0       5.0
1         10001    78.0       NaN      12.0
0         10002     3.0     201.0      34.0
1         10002   234.0     510.0       NaN
0         10003   231.0     765.0      56.0
1         10003     NaN     422.0    2345.0
2         10003     NaN     753.0       NaN
3         10003     NaN    7587.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I missed the `ID` condition. You need to use groupby in that case.

```py
# In one liner
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x:x.reset_index().apply(lambda y: y.shift(-y.first_valid_index())).set_index('index'))
```

Explanation:

- Group the dataframe by ID
- First `apply` (one with `lambda x`) receives the grouped dataframe as parameter

  - `reset_index()` is to make the grouped dataframe starts with index 0 (else it'll use index from the whole dataframe)
- Second `apply` (one with `lambda y`) receives the column of the grouped dataframe as parameter

  - Get the `first_valid_index` and shift it upwards
- As the resetted index is now useless, we give back the `index` column to be used as index

```
        ID  Number  Number 2  Number 3
0  10001.0    25.0       4.0       5.0
1  10001.0    78.0       NaN      12.0
2  10001.0     NaN       NaN       NaN
3  10002.0     3.0     201.0      34.0
4  10002.0   234.0     510.0       NaN
5  10002.0     NaN       NaN       NaN
6  10003.0   231.0     765.0      56.0
7  10003.0     NaN     422.0    2345.0
8  10003.0     NaN     753.0       NaN
9  10003.0     NaN    7587.0       NaN
```

<strike>You can use `apply` to make it work per column. And use `shift` to move the Series upwards</strike>

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.first_valid_index()))
```

Comment: I ran the above and nothing is happening. I also ran `df['Number'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.first_valid_index()))` and the result is it fills `df['Number']` with `df['ID'] `

Answer (score 1):

Using a stacked version of the dataframe, then shifting by the number on leading NaN per group+column:

```
(df.set_index('ID', append=True).stack(dropna=False)
   .groupby(level=[1,2])
   .apply(lambda s: s.shift(-(~s.notna().cummax()).sum()))
   .unstack(-1)
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
       ID Number Number 2 Number 3
1   10001   25.0      4.0        5
2   10001   78.0      NaN       12
3   10001    NaN      NaN      NaN
4   10002    3.0    201.0       34
5   10002  234.0    510.0      NaN
6   10002    NaN      NaN      NaN
7   10003  231.0    765.0       56
8   10003    NaN    422.0     2345
9   10003    NaN    753.0      NaN
10  10003    NaN   7587.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, the first column will always have a value and for any ID, only the last row will have NaNs, if at all

```
# melt to make it a single column, so we drop all the NAN cells/rows
df2=df.melt('ID').dropna(axis=0)

# count the number of values for an ID
df2['ID_Count'] = df2.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()

# Group the result into a set of 3, since we have three columns number, number_2, number_3
df2['new_var'] =  (df2['ID_Count'] // (3))

# Generate a new column name
df2['new_var_group'] = 'Number_' + df2.groupby(['ID','new_var']).cumcount().astype(str)

# finally reverse the melt and gnerate the table same as before
df2 = df2.pivot_table(index=['ID','new_var' ], columns='new_var_group', values='value').reset_index().drop(columns='new_var', axis=1)
df2
```

```
new_var_group   ID  Number_0    Number_1    Number_2
0   10001   25.0    78.0    4.0
1   10001   5.0     12.0    NaN
2   10002   3.0     234.0   201.0
3   10002   510.0   34.0    NaN
4   10003   231.0   765.0   422.0
5   10003   753.0   7587.0  56.0
6   10003   2345.0  NaN     NaN
```